# awk command to find average of a column from a file

Tags: php, awk

I have written an awk command to read from a log file and get the average of a specific column.
The command is :

```
awk '{sum += $NF} END {print sum/NR}' /serach_grater500ms_test.txt
```

Everything is working fine on terminal but when I try to execute this command in php script as follow :

```
$no_of_request=exec("awk '{sum += $NF} END {print sum/NR}' /serach_grater500ms_test.txt");
print_r($no_of_request);
```

It throw me a syntax error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: NF in /home/javed/Downloads/read_log.php on line 11
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a string into a shell script, you need to quote it properly for the shell. The easiest way to do this is to make it a single-quoted literal; this requires transforming the single quotes inside the string.

```
exec('awk \'{sum += $NF} END {print sum/NR}\' /serach_grater500ms_test.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the php string is between double-quote ". The character ' inside has no special meaning, you dont need to escape it. On the other hand the $ (like in `sum += $NF`) is interpreted, so the php replaces `$NF` with its value (empty!).

With Inian's answer the php string is between single-quote '. So the php does not look for variable inside (`$NF` is protected); but you have to escape further \' inside.

You can also have it work with the double-quote of your example; but you escape only the \$ of `$NF` :

```
$no_of_request=exec("awk '{sum += \$NF} END {print sum/NR}' filee");
```